# Restrict execution of concurrent queue in Spring JMS

Tags: spring, spring-jms

Ideally after one queue completes its execution, another queue should start.
I am using Spring JMS. But at a time more than one queue able to execute by which data mismatch occurs.
So can anyone please tell how to restrict concurrent queue or unless first queue ends the 2nd queue cannot be started or all other queues are in waiting.

```
public class MyQueueListener implements MessageListener {

public void onMessage(Message message) {
    try {

        if (message instanceof ObjectMessage) {
            ObjectMessage objectMessage = (ObjectMessage) message;
            MyQueueObject obj= (MyQueueObject)objectMessage.getObject();
            String productId = obj.getProductId();
            IMyService myService;
            myService.updateAllCustomerDetails(productId);
        }

    } catch (JMSException j) {
        j.printStackTrace();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}   


}




<bean id="mySenderService" class="MySenderService">
<property name="jmsTemplate" ref="myjmsTemplate" />
<property name="queue" ref="myQueueDestination" />  
</bean>
<bean id="myQueueDestination" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"> 
<property name="jndiName">
<value>queue/myQueue</value>
</property> 
<property name="resourceRef">
<value>true</value>
</property> 
</bean>
<bean id="myQueueListener" class="MyQueueListener" ></bean> 

<bean id="jmsImportContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
<property name="connectionFactory" ref="connectionFactory" />
<property name="destination" ref="myQueueDestination" />
<property name="messageListener" ref="myQueueListener" /> 
</bean>


mySenderService.sendMessages();
```

Comment: Do you mean concurrent listeners on the same queue? It looks like you're using the term 'queue' whereas you should use the term 'listener'

Comment: Yes.I mean to say to restrict concurrent listener.

Comment: there is the concurrency attribute for that but it's set to 1 by default so I am not sure what the problem can be. Can you show the configuration that you used to register `MyQueueListener`?

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your config. The default concurrency level is 1 (i.e. only one consumer at a time)